# Can someone explain to me why my code is causing an error message in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

This is my code:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=10, A2<=20), A2*1.5, IF(AND(A2>=20, A2<=30), A2*1.35, IF(AND(A2>=40, A2<=50), A2*1.2, A2)))
```

I want to do is write a code that looks at the old prices and updates them by percentage let's say between 10 and €20 it needs to be increased by 50%.

Only I can't see what wrong with my code and why its not working when adding to column B2

Thanks so much for the help

I tried changing the comma to semicolons tried to shorten the code but still no luck.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error message when I paste your formula into an Excel cell.

Comment: You likely should be using a lookup table here instead of nested IFs.

Comment: OK that's weird I'm getting this message, "There's a problem with this formula." And that's about it

Comment: Do you get an error if you type `=AND(A2>=10, A2<=20)` in a new cell? I'm guessing your formula separator is the `;`, even if you mentioned you already tried that.

Comment: wait wait this got accepted by excel? =AND(A2>=10; A2<=20), but it doesn't work on the full code

Comment: Then your formula separator is the `;`, so change all the `,` to `;`. What is your decimal separator?

Comment: It looks like your decimal separator is the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

M. b. you missed the 30 to 40 interval?

```
=IF(AND(A2>=10, A2<=20), A2*1.5, IF(AND(A2>=20, A2<=30), A2*1.35, IF(AND(A2>=30, A2<=40), A2*1.2, A2)))
```

Pls. consider "A2<10" will produce A2 as well as when "A2>50".

For more clearance use ">=" and "<" conditions instead of ">=" and "<=".

We have to guess what is wrong. What are column names on the worksheet? It should be A, B, C, ... not 1, 2, 3, ...

Change the separator in formula by find and replace if required. Temporary put the apostrophe at the start of the formula to enter the formula as a text, perform find and replace then delete the apostrophe.

Comment: Names are not made they're just blanc, column A starts at number 2 with prices

Comment: Pls provide at least the picture of the worksheet. The screenshot of the error will also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the mistake, the numbers with "." need to be indicated by a "," and the codes that use "," need to be ";". that why it didn't work!

I'm so sorry for wasting everyone's time!